# How can we hang the weighted trees so that vertices nearer to root (based on distances, not hop count) lie in upper levels?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees, spanning-tree

I have a set of edge weighted trees, each tree rooted at some vertex. Consider these trees are hung from the roots and vertices are arranged in some levels. I wish to design an algorithm (theoretically) which arranges the vertices such that, vertices nearer to root should lie in upper levels (levels nearer to root). Here, nearer is in terms of weighted distance, not hop count. I am trying to figure out what technique I should use or what parameter should I focus to perform this task. Please share some ideas that can help build the algorithm or procedure. One more help, someone please add a tag for problems related to "Steiner tree".

Comment: it's always good to  use a top level tag. I added combinatorics

Comment: Thanks, I shall use this suggestion.

Comment: Re: the last sentence, you can add any tags to your own post that you please, but currently no more tags can be added (maximum of 5).

Comment: It requires a reputation of 300.